# Evernote: Get a list of all edits

Tags: java, evernote, usage-statistics

I am trying to develop a simple statistics tool to analyse various behaviours of collaborators within an Evernote Notebook using the Evernote Java API.

I need the informations which user edited which note and when.
Even though the documentation is quite good, I am still unable to find the required functionality inside the api.

(**TLDR**:)
Is there a way to access a list of edits of a evernote note using the API?

I am not bound to using the Java SDK so if there is a way, which is limited to using another language, it would be no problem to switch.

Answer (score 0):

Andreas - Did you look into these methods in the API?

[NoteStore.GetNote](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_getNote) and [NoteStore.getNoteApplicationData](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_getNoteApplicationData)

It sounds like this would be a decent place to start at the very least. I cannot say for certain if this will return everything you are looking for though.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you are looking for but [NoteStore#listNoteVersions](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_listNoteVersions) might be the one you want. You can get a list of [NoteVersionId](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Struct_NoteVersionId) and then use another API called [NoteStore#getNoteVersion](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_getNoteVersion) to get metadata to see which note is updated when.

Note that the API is probably only for premium accounts.